# How to create a face when only one vertex is selected?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was watching a video on retopology and saw the uploader extrude a mesh face in a way that I've not seen before.  He's in edit-vertex mode and has a partly completed mesh with an L-shaped bend along its edge.  He then selects the vertex on the inside corner of the L and then appears to click somewhere further out - and this causes an entire face to be created:

[image]

YouTube clip:
https://youtu.be/KNjCaizeal0?t=8m29s

I've been reading through the docs, but can't figure out what key I need to press to do this.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like blender has an addon called 'f2' mode.  Enable it, and then you can create this sort of quad just by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/F2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As he is saying in the video, it's the effect of an add-on called Mesh F2, coming with the standard Blender bundle.
To use it you must go to "user preferences" - "Add-Ons", search for mesh F2, activate the add-on and save the user preferences.
Then in edit mode select an angle vertex and press the F key.